# Processing received data from socket

Tags: java, sockets, io

I am developing a socket application and my application needs to receive xml file over socket. The size of xml files received vary from 1k to 100k. I am now thinking of storing data that I received into a temporary file first, then pass it to the xml parser. I am not sure if it is a proper way to do it.

Another question is if I wanna do as mentioned above, should I pass file object or file path to xml parser?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send it straight to the parser. That's what browsers do. Adding a temp file costs you time and space with no actual benefit.

Comment: Thanks EJP. If InputStream from socket contains some preceding data before XML data, is it ok to skip those data by performing some read() method calls before passing it to parser?

Comment: Sure. Or even skip() it if you happen to know the exact length.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it would work to put a BufferedReader around whatever input stream you have?  It wouldn't put it into a temporary file, but it would let you hang onto that data.  You can set whatever size BufferedReader you need.

Did you write your XML parser?  If you didn't, what will it accept as a parameter?  If you did write it, are you asking about efficiency.  That is to say which object, the path or file, should your parser ask for to be most efficient?

Comment: Hi Raven, I am not writing my own XML parser and the API that I am using takes in InputStream as a parameter to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to store the data from socket to any file. Just read whole the `DataInputStream` into a byte array and you can then do whatever you need. E.g. if needed create a `String` with the xml input to feed the parser. (I am assuming tcp sockets).
If there are preceding data you skip them so as to feed the actual xml data to the parser.